# Football game Loops

Tags: java, loops

So I have this program I am trying to build and it is a simple football game. My only question that is puzzling me is how do I get my program to loop through all these questions. The JOptionPane messages on the bottom are out of place and my code is a little messy I am just wondering if anyone can help me on how I just make my program loop through all these questions and letting the user end it.

```
package football;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Football {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Are you ready for some FOOTBALL?!?!?!");


        String StringTeamOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pick two of the four teams");
        //Input my methods

        String StringBallOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Who has the ball first?");
        //If statement and loop
        String StringPlayOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Did the team pass or run the ball?");
        //If statement and part of loop
        String StringYardage = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How far did the team throw/run?");
        //If statement and calculation also part of loop
        String StringScoreingPlay = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Did the team score?");
        //If statement and part of loop
        String StringPlayAgain = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to play again");
        //loop

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The ball is on the 20 yard line anything over 80 yards will not count");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "End of the quarter!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "End of the game!!!");
        //Messages for explanation
```

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. Would you mind describing it in the following format?: expected behavior, actual behavior, (optionally) errors. Also it would be easier to debug if you post a small, complete runnable code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a boolean flag and a while or do while loop?

```
Boolean keepPlaying = true;

while (keepPlaying) {

// ... All the questions here.
//If input from "Do you want to play again?" is no, set keepPlaying to false.

}
```